# PHP Order Form to Email

Tags: php, forms

I have a pretty long order form for our school website shirt order form.  We offer serveral different options for peopel to choose from. I am getting the order emails but they are very long and contain the name of every item.  How do I recieve an email with just the items ordered and not the entire form with all of the items listed but none ordered?

PHP Action Code:

```
<?php 
    //Form Action
    $_POST['emailAddress'] = "PCLA Registrar<regsitration@paragonlearningacademy.com>";

    $to = 'PCLA Registrar<rxxx.com>' . ', '; 
    $to .= "{$_POST['email']}\r\n";
    $subject = '2016-2017 Shirt Order Form';

    //Parent Information
    $message  = "Parents Name:   {$_POST['parents_name']}\r\n"; 
    $message  = "Students Name:   {$_POST['students_name']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Email Address:   {$_POST['email']}\r\n";  
    $message .= "Phones Number:   {$_POST['phone_number']}\r\n";

    //Short Sleeve T-Shirts
    $message .= "Short Youth Small: {$_POST['short_youth_small']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Short Youth Medium:{$_POST['short_youth_medium']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Short Youth Large: {$_POST['short_youth_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Short Youth XL:   {$_POST['short_youth_xl']}\r\n";

    $message .= "Short Adult Small:  {$_POST['short_adult_small']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Short Adult Medium:{$_POST['short_adult_medium']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Short Adult Large:  {$_POST['short_adult_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Short Adult XL:   {$_POST['short_adult_xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Short Adult 2XL:   {$_POST['short_adult_2xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Short Adult 3XL:   {$_POST['short_adult_3xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Ordered:   {$_POST['tshirts_ordered']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Amount Due:   {$_POST['short_amount_due']}\r\n";

    // Long Sleeve T-Shirts
    $message .= "Long Youth Small:   {$_POST['long_youth_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Long Youth Medium:   {$_POST['long_youth_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Long Youth Large:   {$_POST['long_youth_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Long Youth XL:   {$_POST['long_youth_xl']}\r\n";

    $message .= "Long Adult Small:   {$_POST['long_adult_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Long Adult Medium:   {$_POST['long_adult_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Long Adult Large:   {$_POST['long_adult_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Long Adult XL:   {$_POST['long_adult_xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Long Adult 2XL:   {$_POST['long_adult_2xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Ordered:   {$_POST['long_ordered']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Amount Due:   {$_POST['long_amount_due']}\r\n";

    // Sweatshirts
    $message .= "Sweatshirt Youth Small:  {$_POST['long_youth_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Sweatshirt Youth Medium: {$_POST['long_youth_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Sweatshirt Youth Large: {$_POST['long_youth_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Sweatshirt Youth XL:   {$_POST['long_youth_xl']}\r\n";

    $message .= "Sweatshirt Adult Small: {$_POST['sweat_adult_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Sweatshirt Adult Medium:{$_POST['sweat_adult_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Sweatshirt Adult Large:{$_POST['sweat_adult_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Sweatshirt Adult XL:  {$_POST['sweat_adult_xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Sweatshirt Adult 2XL: {$_POST['sweat_adult_2xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Sweatshirt Adult 3XL: {$_POST['sweat_adult_3xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Ordered:   {$_POST['sweat_ordered']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Amount Due:   {$_POST['sweat_amount_due']}\r\n";

    // Hooded Sweatshirt
    $message .= "Hooded Youth Small:   {$_POST['hooded_youth_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Hooded Youth Medium:   {$_POST['hooded_youth_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Hooded Youth Large:   {$_POST['hooded_youth_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Hooded Youth XL:   {$_POST['hooded_youth_xl']}\r\n";

    $message .= "Hooded Adult Small:   {$_POST['hooded_adult_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Hooded Adult Medium:   {$_POST['hooded_adult_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Hooded Adult Large:   {$_POST['hooded_adult_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Hooded Adult XL:   {$_POST['hooded_adult_xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Hooded Adult 2XL:   {$_POST['hooded_adult_2xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Hooded Adult 3XL:   {$_POST['hooded_adult_3xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Ordered:   {$_POST['hooded_ordered']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Amount Due:   {$_POST['hooded_amount_due']}\r\n";

    // Zip Up Hooded Jacket
    $message .= "Zip Up Youth Small:   {$_POST['zip_up_youth_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Zip Up Youth Medium:   {$_POST['zip_up_youth_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Zip Up Youth Large:   {$_POST['zip_up_youth_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Zip Up Youth XL:   {$_POST['zip_up_youth_xl']}\r\n";

    $message .= "Zip Up Adult Small:   {$_POST['zip_up_adult_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Zip Up Adult Medium:   {$_POST['zip_up_adult_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Zip Up Adult Large:   {$_POST['zip_up_adult_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Zip Up Adult XL:   {$_POST['zip_up_adult_xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Zip Up Adult 2XL:   {$_POST['zip_up_adult_2xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Zip Up Adult 3XL:   {$_POST['zip_up_adult_3xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Ordered:   {$_POST['zip_up_ordered']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Amount Due:   {$_POST['zip_up_amount_due']}\r\n";

    // Polo
    $message .= "Polo Youth Small:   {$_POST['polo_youth_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Polo Youth Medium:   {$_POST['polo_youth_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Polo Youth Large:   {$_POST['polo_youth_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Polo Youth XL:   {$_POST['polo_youth_xl']}\r\n";

    $message .= "Women's Polo Small:   {$_POST['wpolo_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Women's Polo Medium:   {$_POST['wpolo_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Women's Polo Large:   {$_POST['wpolo_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Women's Polo XL:   {$_POST['wpolo_xl']}\r\n";

    $message .= "Men's Polo Small:   {$_POST['mpolo_s']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Men's Polo Medium:   {$_POST['mpolo_m']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Men's Polo Large:   {$_POST['mpolo_large']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Men's Polo XL:   {$_POST['mpolo_xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Men's Polo 2XL:   {$_POST['mpolo_2xl']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Men's Polo 3XL:   {$_POST['mpolo_2xl']}\r\n";

    $message .= "Total Ordered:   {$_POST['polo_ordered']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Amount Due:   {$_POST['polo_amount_due']}\r\n";

    //Totals
    $message .= "Total Amount Ordered:   {$_POST['total_ordered']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Total Amount Due:   {$_POST['total_amount']}\r\n";

    //General Agreements
    $message .= "Shirts Required:  {$_POST['shirts']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Exchanges:  {$_POST['exchange']}\r\n";
    $message .= "Payment:  {$_POST['payment']}\r\n";

    if ($_POST['comments_questions']) {
        $message .= "Comments:  {$_POST['comments_questions']}\r\n";
    }

    $headers = "From: " . $_POST['emailAddress'] . "\n"; 
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$additional_headers);

    header("Location: http://www.paragonlearningacademy.com/shirt_thanks.htm");

    exit;   
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Attention! Your order form can be used to send spam emails, because everyone can modify the email headers. You have to filter the $_POST['emailAddress'] variable.

```
$_POST['emailAddress'] = strtr(trim($_POST['emailAddress']), array("\n"=>'', "\r" => ''));
```

The easiest would be to add a simple if condition for each item like that:

```
if ($_POST['short_youth_small']) {
    $message .= "Short Youth Small: {$_POST['short_youth_small']}\r\n";
}
if ($_POST['short_youth_medium']) {
   $message .= "Short Youth Medium:{$_POST['short_youth_medium']}\r\n";
}
```

You will have to adjust the name of the variable in every condition like in the text inside the brackets

It would be even better to put all the different variables in an array and walk the array with a foreach(...).

example:

```
$_POST['emailAddress'] = strtr(trim($_POST['emailAddress']), array("\n"=>'', "\r" => ''));

   //Form Action
   $_POST['emailAddress'] = "PCLA Registrar<regsitration@paragonlearningacademy.com>";

   $to = 'PCLA Registrar<registration@paragonlearningacademy.com>' . ', '; 
   $to .= "{$_POST['email']}\r\n";
   $subject = '2016-2017 Shirt Order Form';


   //Parent Information
   $message  = "Parents Name:   {$_POST['parents_name']}\r\n"; 
   $message  = "Students Name:   {$_POST['students_name']}\r\n";
   $message .= "Email Address:   {$_POST['email']}\r\n";  
   $message .= "Phones Number:   {$_POST['phone_number']}\r\n";

$fields = array (
    // variable name => title
    'short_youth_small' => 'Short Youth Small',
    'short_youth_medium' => 'Short Youth Medium',
    // other variables ...
);
// walk the array
foreach ($fields as $key => $title) {
    if ($_POST[$key]) {
        $message .= $title . ": " . $_POST[$key] . "\r\n";
    }
}
   //General Agreements
   $message .= "Shirts Required:  {$_POST['shirts']}\r\n";
   $message .= "Exchanges:  {$_POST['exchange']}\r\n";
   $message .= "Payment:  {$_POST['payment']}\r\n";

   if ($_POST['comments_questions']) {
     $message .= "Comments:  {$_POST['comments_questions']}\r\n";
   }

   $headers = "From: " . $_POST['emailAddress'] . "\n"; 
   $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();


   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$additional_headers);

   header("Location: http://www.example.com/shirt_thanks.htm");

   exit;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I have this form password protected - do I still need the code to prevent spam?

Comment: The chance for some bots to find this issue runs to 0 if the form is password protected, however there is always a chance that some user with a password tries to exploit it to cause your school some harm. Since it is just one line of code, i would really recommend you inserting it.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each $message in  if block that only concatenates data if there's data in it.

**EXAMPLE**

```
if("" != trim($_POST['long_adult_large']) {
   $message .= "Long Adult Large:   {$_POST['long_adult_large']}\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Sure - if it meets your criteria for an answer please mark it as one - or upvote it as helpful. Same rules apply to all answers that people take the time to write for you.